# Проблема на странице товара Magento

Tags: cms, input, button, magento, themes

ситуация следующая. кнопка покупки работает нормально, то есть добавляет при нажатии в корзину. но есть "но"! рядом возле этой кнопки есть input для указания количества товара. вводим например 10, нажимаем купить и в корзине оказывается один товар, а не 10 необходимых. почему не происходит взаимодействие input с кнопкой и как это починить?

**наблюдение**: то же самое происходит в базовой теме, а вот в rwd все работает адеквтано, то есть ввел количество, нажал кнопку, в корзине указанное вами количество товара.

Comment: ответ на выше поставленный вопрос оставил [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/516017/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-input?lq=1)