# запрет на input

Tags: html, css, cms, input, magento

Работаю с magento, на странице товара есть input для ввода количества товара. Что хочу? Хочу чтобы при вводе цифр и нажатии на Enter не реагировало на действие, а реагировало только при нажатии на кнопку "Добавит в корзину". Почему так? Потому что перенаправляет непонятно куда. Как сделать так, что бы input не реагировал на Enter?

Comment: На enter вероятно реагирует кнопка submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ нашелся внезапно.

```
<?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
    <span class="number-mark">
        <input id="qty"  class="input-text qty" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" maxlength="12" name="qty" type="text" value="1" />
    </span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

а вот и необходимый скрипт

```
<script>

    document.getElementById("qty").onkeypress= function(event){
        event= event || window.event;
        if (event.charCode && (event.charCode < 48 || event.charCode > 57))// проверка на event.charCode - чтобы пользователь мог нажать backspace, enter, стрелочку назад...
        return false;
    };
    8
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно просто отлавливать событие Enter и ничего при этом не выполнять

```
$("#id_of_input").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        event.preventDefault();

    }
});
```

Можно ещё почитать на англ. сайте - [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/enter-key-press-event-in-javascript)

Comment: идея хороша, но у меня она чего то не срабатывает)